# How to pass value to parameterized constructors if there objects are being created as data members of another class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, constructor

I am trying to make a Chess Game in C++ using OOPS concepts but face the following error:

```
src/Game.cpp:6:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘Player::Player()’
 Game::Game(): player1(1), player2(0){
                                    ^
In file included from include/Game.h:4:0,
                 from src/Game.cpp:2:
```

Here is my code:

Player.h

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <string>
#include <King.h>
#include <Knight.h>
#include <Pawn.h>
#include <Queen.h>
#include <Bishop.h>
#include <Rook.h>
using namespace std;
class Player{
    public:
        Player(int color);
        void getMove();   
        int playerColor;             // 0 if player is black, 1 otherwise.   
    private:
        string move;                
        // each player has the following pieces.
        King king;                          
        Queen queen;
        Bishop bishop[2];
        Rook rook[2];
        Knight knight[2];
        Pawn paws[8];
};
#endif
```

Player.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Player::Player(int color)
:playerColor(color){
    
}
```

Game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <Pieces.h>
#include <Player.h>

class Game:public Player
{
    public:
        Game();
    private:
        Player player1;
        Player player2;
        Square cells[8][8];
        bool gameStatus;
        bool whiteTurn;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Game.h"
#include "Pieces.h"
using namespace std;

Game::Game(): player1(1), player2(0){
    
}
```

I am also getting similar error while creating various piece objects in Player.h file
How to create these objects?

Comment: Start by cleaning up your includes. It appears that you have mislabeled Player.h and Player.cpp in your post. You have circular includes (Game.h includes Player.h which include Game.h), and you misuse the `#include <>` syntax to include local files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source of the error is that `Game` is derived from `Player`.

```
Game::Game(): player1(1), player2(0){
}
```

is the same as

```
Game::Game(): Player(), player1(1), player2(0){
}
```

My suggestion is to not make `Player` a base class of `Game`.

```
// class Game : public Player
class Game
{
    ...
}
```